# Item level Edit permissions overwritten by List Settings

Tags: permissions, item-level-permissions

With the list setting: Create items and edit items that were created by the user, it is not possible to let another user to update the item even we give to him Full Control to the item.

With the list setting: Create and edit all items, the creator can edit all his items even we give to him Read access to the item

This has been tested in 2010 and 2013 on Premise

What is the best solution to avoid the user which we have change his permissions to Read access to Edit his item?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Can you give everyone edit rights to all list items and restrict what they see by creating views? How critical/confidential is your data? Do you expect your users to create personal views?

As your list grows, item level permissions introduces some complexity to your list. But there are cases that you might need them, for example, employee survey, confidential documents. If your list items are not confidential, I suggest you take the former option. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but they are confidential